# How to set global variable

Tags: javascript, angular

```
export class SharedService { 
isDarkroom = false;

createDarkromInstance(width, height) {
    this.darkroom = new Darkroom('#img', {
        // Size options
        minWidth: 300,
        minHeight: 300,
        maxWidth: 900,
        maxHeight: 900,
        ratio: width/height,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',

        plugins: {
            crop: {
                minHeight: 50,
                minWidth: 50
            },
            save: {
                callback: function() {
                    this.darkroom.selfDestroy();
                    this.imageCroppedBase64 = this.darkroom.canvas.toDataURL();
                    this.isDarkroom = true;
                }
            },
            brush: false
        },

        initialize: function() {
            let cropPlugin =    this.plugins['crop'].requireFocus();
        }
    });
}
```

How to set global "isDarkroom" variable in callback function when i use this.isDarkrom locale variable is set. I read something about call() and bind(), but i tried to use without success.

Comment: Maybe `window.darkroom =  this.darkroom;` ? ... which will expose the _inner_ function as a global one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your callback into a fat arrow function, as this will keep the `this` reference untouched:

```
            callback: () => {
                this.darkroom.selfDestroy();
                this.imageCroppedBase64 = this.darkroom.canvas.toDataURL();
                this.isDarkroom = true;
            }
```

Comment: when i change to arrow function i have error that this.darkroom is undefined

Comment: I change let darkroom = new Darkroom(..... calback: () => { darkroom.selfDestroy(); .... } and now it's work